# Repeating code, bad practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this piece of code

```
@liked_tweet = LikedTweet.new
@liked_tweet = @liked_tweet.existing_like( params[:tweet_id], current_user.id )
```

Is there any better way how to write this? I have a feeling that this is just bad practise. Or is it perfectly ok?

thank you very much for your time

Comment: Could you please explain what your code does?

Answer (score 1):

```
@liked_tweet = LikedTweet.where(tweet_id: params[:tweet_id], user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for thank you. I'm going to accept this as an answer asap

Answer (score 0):

```
@liked_tweet = @liked_tweet.existing_like( params[:tweet_id], current_user.id ) || LikedTweet.new
```